# Discord bot чтение личных сообщений от пользователя JS?

Tags: javascript, бот, discord

Как мне сделать так, чтобы бот читал сообщение, только от определенного пользователя(допустим по ID), сохранял его сообщение и выводил их в определенный канал?
Обязательно на JS

```js
if (message.channel.type === 'dm') { // если тип канала - DM (личные сообщения) . . .
  if (message.author.id === "ID_пользователя") { // если ID пользователя === . . .
    client.channels.cache.get('ID_канала').send(`${message.content}`); // находим канал по его ID и отправляем туда контент сообщения.
  }
}
```

Comment: Ну и в чём проблема в событии получения сообщения от пользователя проверять его id?

Comment: @Doofy у меня все готово, вот только эта "фича" не работает
я пытался проверять

```if (message.channel.type === 'dm') { // если тип канала - DM (личные сообщения) . . .
  if (message.author.id === "ID_пользователя") { // если ID пользователя === . . .
    client.channels.cache.get('ID_канала').send(`${message.content}`); // находим канал по его ID и отправляем туда контент сообщения.
  }
}```
но оно не работает

Comment: @Doofy client.on('message' , msg =>

Comment: @Doofy понимаю, та же проблема

Comment: У меня работает. Отправляю боту личное сообщение и общем чате оно появляется. Возможно боту не хватает прав для отправки сообщения или неверный id канала

Comment: @Doofy у бота права администратора. Можно посмотреть код?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
client.on('message', message => {

  if (message.channel.type == 'dm') {

    if (message.author.id == '<user_id') {
      client.channels.cache.get('<chanell_id>').send(`${message.content}`);
    }
  }
});

client.login('<token>');
```